# Component starts to break after some time - react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a component that will take any image and make it spin in circles.
I managed to do so but appears I have an issue with setting the interval cleanup function as it starts to switch quickly from one state to another and the picture spins like crazy.

This is the spinner component

```
import classes from './Spinner.module.css'
import { useState , useEffect} from 'react';
const Spinner = (props) =>{
    const [Timer, setTimer] = useState('5');
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            let newT;
            if(Timer==='5'){
                newT='1';
            }
            else{
                newT='5';
            }
            
            setTimer(newT);
        }, 2000);
        console.log(Timer);
        return clearInterval(interval);
        
    }, [Timer])
    
    return <img style={{animation: `${classes.spin} ${Timer}s linear infinite`}} src={props.img} alt="img"/>

};

export default Spinner ;
```

Spin CSS :

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the interval created cleanup function it did not work, since it was not in a function.

Change was in the `return` function of the `useEffect` component.

```
const Spinner = (props) => {

  const [Timer, setTimer] = useState("5");
  
  useEffect(() => {

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prevState) => prevState ==='5' ? '1'  : '5');
    }, 2000);

    console.log(Timer);

    return ()=>{clearInterval(interval)};

  }, [Timer]);

  return (
    <img
      style={{ animation: `${classes.spin} ${Timer}s linear infinite` }}
      src={props.img}
      alt="img"
    />
  );
};
```